# WebRTC video streaming through a server

Tags: javascript, node.js, html, video-streaming, webrtc

I wanna run the stream from client side then join from server to client
. How can I stream the video through a server to another Viewers? Is this possible?

Comment: Are you trying to mix audio streams into one record?

Comment: audio not required

Comment: What do you mean by "join"?

Comment: connect from server to client by url or socket.io maybe

Comment: You can set a `<video>` element `src` to the URL where you serve the media. Not certain what you are trying achieve at client side?

Comment: Maybe I did not understand the structure correctly? But I want one client must broadcast to the server, and the server broadcasting to a lot of viewers

Comment: stream camera -> server -> viewers

Comment: What issue are you having at code? See https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Take a look @ https://www.webrtc-experiment.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would like to try and point you in the right direction.

First, lets understand a little more about how WebRTC works.

In WebRTC you have a websocket that is called the bridge, the bridge's role is to help broker a connection between two or more peers.

Generaly speaking, the bridge uses STUN/TURN servers along with SDP Protocol to help establish the connections between peers.

STUN servers are used to establish p2p udp conenctions by punch holes through NAT.

If the STUN fails to punch a whole (ie there is a firewall), a TURN server is used as a hub & spoke (ie relays data though the TURN server).

The full WebRTC stack includes video/audio streaming with vp8/vp9/h264 codecs & data is packaged using RTP.

Lucky for you there is a node-js library that implments almost the entire stack.

https://github.com/js-platform/node-webrtc

The library essentially provides you a WebRTC data channel.
There is no support for "Media Streams" and thus I assume you need to build the  encoding/decoding and RTP packaging yourself.

However, there is a discussion here on how to stream audio/video with the data channel:

https://github.com/js-platform/node-webrtc/issues/156

Now, your specific question, how to stream from a "server"?

Well WebRTC is generally p2p, however you could setup a "Server Peer" and designate it as having a source channel only (ie there is no input channel).

This peer then becomes the "server" and all the other peers can view its contents when they connect.

Hope that helps.

Cheers!